# help understanding iptables router script and error

Tags: networking, server, iptables, routing

Hello I have this routing script that I'm using which runs when all the network interfaces are up:

```
#!/bin/sh

PATH=/usr/sbin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin

#
# delete all existing rules.
#
iptables -F
iptables -t nat -F
iptables -t mangle -F
iptables -X

# Always accept loopback traffic
iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT


# Allow established connections, and those not coming from the outside
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state NEW -i ! wlan0 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i wlan0 -o eth0 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

# Allow outgoing connections from the LAN side.
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o wlan0 -j ACCEPT

# Masquerade.
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o wlan0 -j MASQUERADE

# Don't forward from the outside to the inside.
iptables -A FORWARD -i wlan0 -o wlan0 -j REJECT

# Enable routing.
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

wlan0 is my wifi connection to my android phones wifi tether, ip range is 192.168.43.0/24
eth0 is my LAN connection, ip range: 10.1.1.0/24

I've noticed when the script gets to this line:

```
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state NEW -i ! wlan0 -j ACCEPT
```

It comes up with the error:

```
Bad argument `wlan0'
Try `iptables -h' or 'iptables --help' for more information.
```

**Being a noob with iptables, I'm not too sure what is wrong.**

Would anyone be able to enlighten me on this?

Comment: You've swapped the `-i` and `!` parameters. See the manual page of iptables  (or iptables-extensions for modern versions).

Comment: wow... it was that easy, I feel stupid.

Also how would I forward that port from the outside into my lan?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future reference or for anyone looking at this page here is the finished script:

```
#!/bin/sh

PATH=/usr/sbin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin

#
# delete all existing rules.
#
iptables -F
iptables -t nat -F
iptables -t mangle -F
iptables -X

# Always accept loopback traffic
iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT

# Allow established connections, and those not coming from the outside
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state NEW ! -i wlan0 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i wlan0 -o eth0 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

# Allow outgoing connections from the LAN side.
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o wlan0 -j ACCEPT

# Masquerade.
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o wlan0 -j MASQUERADE

# Don't forward from the outside to the inside.
iptables -A FORWARD -i wlan0 -o wlan0 -j REJECT

#Port Forward Unifed remote
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 9512 -j ACCEPT -i wlan0
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 9512 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.1.1.12:9512
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -d 10.1.1.12 -p tcp --dport 9512 -j SNAT --to-source 10.1.1.1

# Drop outside traffic except ssh
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport ssh -j ACCEPT -i wlan0
iptables -A INPUT -j DROP -p tcp -i wlan0

# Enable routing.
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```